# Logical volume not found in volume group

Tags: centos, filesystems, partition, lvm, data-recovery

I need to increase the size of `centos_s0106ac9e17b4312300-root`

I am trying `sudo lvextend -L +10G /dev/mapper/centos_s0106ac9e17b4312300-rootJESSE`

but getting   `Logical volume rootJESSE not found in volume group centos_s0106ac9e17b4312300.`

```
sda                                   8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                8:1    0   200M  0 part  
├─sda2                                8:2    0     1G  0 part  
└─sda3                                8:3    0 445.9G  0 part  
  ├─centos_s0106ac9e17b4312300-swap 253:8    0  31.4G  0 lvm   
  ├─centos_s0106ac9e17b4312300-home 253:9    0 364.5G  0 lvm   
  └─centos_s0106ac9e17b4312300-root 253:10   0    50G  0 lvm   /mnt/centos_s0106ac9e17b4312300-rootJESSE

[liveuser@localhost-live /]$ sudo vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               centos00
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               930.31 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              238160
  Alloc PE / Size       238159 / <930.31 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       1 / 4.00 MiB
  VG UUID               nfnzo3-i6kf-w6Fi-qSgD-UQcj-EAL3-0qrmXK
   
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               centos_s0106ac9e17b43123
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <485.09 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              124182
  Alloc PE / Size       124181 / 485.08 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       1 / 4.00 MiB
  VG UUID               VyxNSf-Ke6x-wVkq-t4Up-UyjQ-Jron-yWLflf
   
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               centos_s0106ac9e17b4312300
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               445.93 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              114159
  Alloc PE / Size       114158 / <445.93 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       1 / 4.00 MiB
  VG UUID               Swvxel-gX0y-q1xF-ZMeU-irH8-9KCu-RHpBPp
   
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               nvmeVg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        7
  Metadata Sequence No  11
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                7
  Act PV                7
  VG Size               <325.94 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              83440
  Alloc PE / Size       83200 / 325.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       240 / 960.00 MiB
  VG UUID               sM2ZQz-ke7H-543U-EylK-pO25-0G6S-jhV57f
```

Answer (score 3):

The logical volume is called `root`, not `rootJESSE`. It's mounted on `/mnt/centos_s0106ac9e17b4312300-rootJESSE` but you need to use  `<vg_name>/<lv_name>` for `lvextend`, not the mountpoint, so you need to run

```
sudo lvextend -L +10G centos_s0106ac9e17b4312300/root
```

I would also recommend using `--resizefs` to resize the filesystem too (otherwise you'd need to do that after the `lvextend` call with `xfs_growfs` (for XFS) or `resize2fs` (for Ext4)).

You also don't have 10 GiB of free space in the `centos_s0106ac9e17b4312300` volume group so the `lvextend` command will still fail. There's no extra space on your `sda` drive so I'm not sure what is your plan here.

Comment: I was planning on reducing /home and increasing /

Comment: That should be possible, if you are not using XFS as filesystem for your `/home` (which can't be reduced and is default on CentOS) and you need to do that first. You can use the `lvreduce` command which has same syntax as `lvextend`.